# Laravel blade: Overwrite section using show

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have default blade , it will have 3 section and one yield content as like below

```
<div id="wrapper">  
            @show   
                @section('sidemenu')        
                    @include('partials.admin_sidemenu')             

            <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
                @show   
                    @section('navheader')
                        @include('partials.admin_navheader')    

                @show
                    @yield('content')


                @show   
                    @section('footer')                          
                        @include('partials.admin_footer')

            </div>
        </div>
```

In my login blade i don't want to show header,menu and footer so i have used below code to overwrite the header menu and footer

```
@extends('layout.default')
@section('sidemenu')
@stop 
@section('navheader')
@stop 
@section('content')
    Login Form
@stop

@section('footer')
@stop
```

It's not over writing the footer content ... it was a issue?

How can i handle this?

Thanks Advance

Comment: better to have different layouts that extend layout.default and where You include different partials.

Comment: @num8er ..the header and menu section are overwritten..except the footer..Why it's happens i don't know

Comment: Try to cleanup view cache: php artisan view:clear

Answer (score 3):

You forgot about putting: `@show` at the end of section declaration:

```
@section('footer')                          
    @include('partials.admin_footer')
@show
```